# How to find start and end date of a period of two months? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

How to find start and end date of a period of two months?

Example:

- Current date: 09/02/2015; Start date: 01/01/2015; Deadline: 02/28/15.
- Current date: 05/06/2015; Start date: 01/05/2015; Deadline: 30/06/15

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have SQL Server 2012 or newer, this will work:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '09-Feb-2015'

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0) AS Start,
        DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Date)+1,0))
```

If you do have SQL 2012, you can use [EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0) AS Start,
        EOMONTH(@Date)
```

**UPDATE**

After you added in the comments that you want bimonthly, and assuming that means you are splitting the year into 2-month segments with JAN/FEB as the first pair, MAR/APR being the next and so on, this will work:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -1+MONTH(@Date)%2, @Date)), 0) AS StartOfPeriod,
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(@Date)%2, @Date)) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: I need to be bimonthly

Comment: This works exactly as you requested. the first day of previous month and last day of specified month.

Comment: Not exactly. I need the start date and end date according to the current date two months. If the current date was 01/05/15, the starting date should be 01/01/15 and the final date 02/28/15.

Comment: So how do you define the "current two months"?

Comment: a year would be divided into six periods, that is, every 2 months. In this case I need to start and end date of the period according to the current date.